# How to remove a value between the 5th and 6th separator using SED?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

Remove value between 5 and 6 separator:

```
000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;526;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000
```

We need to get:

```
000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000
```

Comment: You could use a better title, eg "how to remove value between separators using sed"

Comment: Hint: you might have a look cat `cut` instead

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can do this:

```
s='000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;526;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000'

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$6=""} 1' <<< "$s"

000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000
```

- `FS=OFS=";"` sets input and output field separators as `;`
- `$6=""` makes 6th field empty
- `1` prints the whole record

Comment: and on the SED someone knows?

Comment: For `sed` use this: `sed -E 's/^(([^;]*;){5})[^;]*/\1/' <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 1):

Let's define your string as `s`:

```
$ s='000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;526;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000'
```

To remove the sixth field:

```
$ echo "$s" | sed -E 's/(([^;]*;){5})[^;]*/\1/'
000000000000;00000000000000;2;NONE;true;;246;101;100;2;1;;;;;;8;101/100.0000.99.99;526/125.000.122.000
```

#### How it works

We use a single sed substitution command:

```
s/(([^;]*;){5})[^;]*/\1/
```

Here, `(([^;]*;){5})` matches the first five fields and saves them in group 1.

`[^;]*` matches the field that follows.   In other words, it matches the sixth field.

The replacement text is just `\1` which means group 1 which is the first five fields.  Thus, the sixth field is removed and not replaced.